# How to overwrite data on an existing excel sheet while preserving all other sheets?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe `df` which I want to overwrite to a sheet `Data` of an excel file while preserving all the other sheets since other sheets have formulas linked to sheet `Data`

I used the following code but it does not overwrite an existing sheet, it just creates a new sheet with the name  `Data 1`

```
with pd.ExcelWriter(filename, engine="openpyxl", mode="a") as writer:
     df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name="Data")
```

Is there a way to overwrite on an existing sheet?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can do it using **[`openpyxl`](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/):**

```
import pandas as pd
from openpyxl import load_workbook

book = load_workbook(filename)
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(filename, engine='openpyxl') 
writer.book = book

writer.sheets = dict((ws.title, ws) for ws in book.worksheets)

df.to_excel(writer, "Data")

writer.save()
```

You need to initialize `writer.sheets` in order to let `ExcelWriter` know about the sheets. Otherwise, it will create a new sheet with the name that you pass.