# Pandas index match multiple dataframes with multiple criteria

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to make python read an excel file, then create dataframes from .csv files who are named after rows in the excel file and index data from the .csv files and paste them in the excel file.

the excel file has been put in a dataframe, which has the following layout:

```
     Name  Location      Date Check_2  ...  Volume  VWAP  $Volume  Trades
0  Orange  New York  20200501       X  ...     NaN   NaN      NaN     NaN
1   Apple     Minsk  20200504       X  ...     NaN   NaN      NaN     NaN
```

The empty rows should be filled with data that is indexed from .csv files who have been put in a dataframe, which looks like this:

```
  Name      Date      Time  Open  High   Low  Close  Volume  VWAP  Trades
4   Orange  20200501  15:30:00  5.50  5.85  5.45   5.70    1500  5.73      95
5   Orange  20200501  17:00:00  5.65  5.70  5.50   5.60    1600  5.65      54
6   Orange  20200501  20:00:00  5.80  5.85  5.45   5.81    1700  5.73      41
7   Orange  20200501  22:00:00  5.60  5.84  5.45   5.65    1800  5.75      62
8   Orange  20200504  15:30:00  5.40  5.87  5.45   5.75    1900  5.83      84
9   Orange  20200504  17:00:00  5.50  5.75  5.40   5.60    2000  5.72      94
10  Orange  20200504  20:00:00  5.80  5.83  5.44   5.50    2100  5.40      55
11  Orange  20200504  22:00:00  5.40  5.58  5.37   5.80    2200  5.35      87
0    Apple  20200504  15:30:00  3.70  3.97  3.65   3.75    1000  3.60      55
1    Apple  20200504  17:00:00  3.65  3.95  3.50   3.80    1200  3.65      68
2    Apple  20200504  20:00:00  3.50  3.83  3.44   3.60    1300  3.73      71
3    Apple  20200504  22:00:00  3.55  3.58  3.35   3.57    1400  3.78      81
4    Apple  20200505  15:30:00  3.50  3.85  3.45   3.70    1500  3.73      95
5    Apple  20200505  17:00:00  3.65  3.70  3.50   3.60    1600  3.65      54
6    Apple  20200505  20:00:00  3.80  3.85  3.45   3.81    1700  3.73      41
7    Apple  20200505  22:00:00  3.60  3.84  3.45   3.65    1800  3.75      62
```

I have been struggling with filling these empty cells, because I haven't been able to find a way to properly index match across these 2 dataframes.

For example, trying:

```
intradayho = rdf2[(rdf2['Time']=='15:30:00')]
indexopen = pd.DataFrame(intradayho['Open'])

rdf1['Open'] = rdf1.Date.map(intradayho.set_index('Date')['Open'].to_dict())
print("Open prices rdf1")
print(rdf1['Open'])
```

produces:

```
Open prices rdf1
0    5.5
1    3.7
```

but only takes account into date, so it will copy the open value of the 'Date' column, not 'Name' and 'Date', which is a problem because those are the 2 values that need to be matched.

also, this code produces the following error:

> A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

but when I try to fix that with

```
rdf1.loc[rdf1['Open']] = rdf1.Date.map(intradayho.set_index('Date')['Open'].to_dict())
```

I get an error:

> KeyError: "None of [Float64Index([nan, nan], dtype='float64')] are in the [index]"

Which doesn't make sense to me, because the whole goal is to fill these 'NaN' values.

Can someone here help me out with making something that can index match data from these dataframes and write it to the Excel file?

Thanks!

EDIT:
Forgot to post my full code, here it is:

```
import pandas as pd
import os

#Opening 'Test Tracker.xlsx' to find entities to download
TEST = pd.ExcelFile("Trackers\TEST Tracker.xlsx")
df1 = TEST.parse("Entries")

values1 = df1[['Name', 'Location', 'Date', 'Check_2',
           'Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close', 'Volume', 'VWAP', '$Volume', 
'Trades']]

#Searching for every row that contains the value 'X' in the column 'Check_2'
rdf1 = values1[values1.Check_2.str.contains("X")]

#Printing dataframe to check
print("First Dataframe")
print(rdf1)

#creating a list for the class objects
Fruits = []

#Generating dataframes from classobjects
for idx, rows in rdf1.iterrows():
    fle = os.path.join('Entities', rows.Location, rows.Name, 'TwoHours.csv')
    col_list = ['Name', 'Date', 'Time', 'Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close', 'Volume', 'VWAP', 'Trades']
    df3 = pd.read_csv(fle, usecols=col_list, sep=";")
    Fruits.append(df3)

rdf2 = pd.concat(Fruits)
print("Printing Full Data Frame")
print(rdf2)

intradayh = rdf2[(rdf2['Time']>'15:30:00') & (rdf2['Time']<'22:00:00')]
intradayho = rdf2[(rdf2['Time']=='15:30:00')]
indexopen = pd.DataFrame(intradayho['Open'])
intradayhc = rdf2[(rdf2['Time']=='22:00:00')]
indexclose = pd.DataFrame(intradayhc['Close'])

rdf1.loc[rdf1['Open']] = rdf1.Date.map(intradayho.set_index('Date')['Open'].to_dict())
print("Open prices rdf1")
print(rdf1['Open'])
```

EDIT: Desired output as requested in the comments:

```
  Name  Location      Date    Open   High   Low    close  volume  VWAP ...
0  Orange  New York  20200501  5.5    5.95  5.45    5.65   6600   5.71  ...
1   Apple     Minsk  20200504  3.7    3.83  3.35    3.57   4900   3.69 ...
```

I am going for a 1 to 1 match in 'Open', a max value in 'High', a min value in 'Low', a 1 to 1 match in 'Close', a sum value for 'Volume' and 'Trades'. an average for 'VWAP' and the value of 'Volume * VWAP' in '$Volume'.

Comment: Appears like all you need to do is a simple merge. Struggling to understand your question though.Can you manually construct expected 2 or three rows of expected output and share?

Comment: Thank you for your response. Yes, I updated the post with the desired output

Comment: Nice, for the Open and High are you looking for 1 to 1 match or a mean? Also we cant see Apple in the second dataframe. Can you update it please as well? One thing with the forum is there are quick answers when people can see input and output.

Comment: Okay than you for the tip. I will update the post with the entire dataframe

Comment: Not entire dataframe! Just give a sample of what best presents the situation.

Comment: I tried to concatenate it a bit, but this is already a sample file with sample code so i try my best to reduce it

Comment: O by the way, I am going for a 1 to 1 match in 'Open', a max value in 'High', a min value in 'Low', a 1 to 1 match in 'Close', a sum value for 'Volume' and 'Trades'. an average for 'VWAP' and the value of 'Volume * VWAP' in '$Volume'.

Comment: Please check your high values. I didnt quite get how you were choosing the ones in your output. Happy to revise the query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`df`, your nan datframe and `df2`; your bigger dataframe with all data

Use `groupby` together with `.agg()` to find multiple aggregations on multiple columns

```
df2=df1.groupby(['Name','Date']).agg(Open=('Open','first'), Close=('Close','last'),High=('High','max'),Low=('Low','min'),Volume=('Volume','sum'),VWAP=('VWAP','mean')).reset_index()
```

One way is then to do an inner merge and slice the updated columns

```
result = pd.merge(df2, df, how='inner', on=['Name', 'Date']).iloc[:,:-4]
```

or
 after aggregation, use `combine_first` and drop all the `NaNs`

```
result= (df.set_index('Date').combine_first(df2.set_index('Date')).reset_index())
result=result[k.notna()]
```

result

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your help. Unfortunately this does not seem to reproduce your results in my code. It is returning the final dataframe, but all the values are still: NaN. I think that the issue is that your code adjusts the columns names for some reason, as my terminal is returning the columns back as: "Open_X", "Close_X", "Open_Y,", .... Therefore I think that python does not recognize them, but I am not sure. I hope you can help to fix that issue

Comment: O i now see that you updated it with something, ill check that

Comment: The code should work. Just ensure you put in the right column names. in the `agg` function, please remember it is `.agg(NewName=(ColumnName, function))`. In this case, I made `NewName` same as `ColumnName`. Just check column names it will be alright

Comment: Unfortunately your second option didn't work out for me either. There are a few things i do not understand about your code and that might be it. you said: df = NaN dataframe, in which I think you mean the first dataframe (which is rdf1 for me) which represents the excel file. Then you say that df2 = the big one, which i get. But in your code, you seem to use 'df', 'df1' and 'df2', so I messed around with these but didnt got it to work. Also, you use result=result[k.notna()], but 'k' is not defined and swapping it with 'result' or 'rdf1' doesn't work either

Comment: The 'output' for me is: "NaN' in each column that was empty already, for if you wonder

Comment: Me bad. The NaN is df, the bigger one is df1. I transform df1 into df2 by grouping. I then use merge df2(transformed df1) with df. Does that help

Comment: Yes that works perfectly and matches the data in the right columns! thanks!. Now could you also help me to append the new rows back to the excel file located in "Trackers\TEST Tracker.xlsx"? (to note, the column names of the new rows do change to '_x', so that could be an issue for that)

Comment: For excel, maybe this could help. Sorry have run short of time. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61933021/how-to-overwrite-data-on-an-existing-excel-sheet-while-preserving-all-other-shee

Comment: Also remember you can save the df by df.to_csv(filename).

Comment: Thank you for the link, ill go look at it. have a nice day