# How to write a dataframe to excel, SPECIFICALLY to an existing sheet by not overwriting existing data

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

I need to write multiple dataframes to an excel file. These dataframes needs to be written to a specific sheet and it should not overwrite existing data on that sheet.

The code I have is as follows:

```
excelbook = test.xlsx
book = load_workbook(excelbook)
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(excelbook, engine = 'openpyxl')
writer.book = book
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name = 'apple', startcol=5, startrow=0)

writer.save()
writer.close()
```

Problem with my code is, each time I run it to write a dataframe, it is creating a new sheet in the excel file. For example, if the sheet name I need is "apple", then since I'm running this piece of code 3 times (to write 3 dataframes to the same sheet), it is creating a new sheet each time and naming them as - "apple1", "apple2" and "apple3"

**I need to write multiple dataframes to the same excel file, to the same sheet in that file, without overwriting the existing data in the sheet.**

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: "without overwriting the existing data in the sheet". What is the rule that tells you where on the sheet the new data should go?

Comment: This should fix it for you; Please upvote the answer if it helps  @ Mayank Porwal https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61933021/how-to-overwrite-data-on-an-existing-excel-sheet-while-preserving-all-other-shee

Comment: Hi! So, I have this piece of code in 3 separate places in the program, and each time I'm giving specific row and col values using - startcol=xx, startrow=xx (these values change each time).

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47737220/append-dataframe-to-excel-with-pandas/47738103

Comment: Hello Mayank! I did try this solution. The issue with that is, out of the 3 times I'm writing to the excel file, the first time I'm creating a new sheet with the name 'apple'. For the remaining 2 dataframes, I used the code you mentioned, however it is writing the dataframes to the default sheet and not the one I created ('apple').