# Keep the original sheet existing while creating a new one in the same excel file

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I am trying to copy 3 columns from "Old Sheet"(which already exists) to "New Sheet" (which hasn't been created yet). The excel filee is as follows.
[image]

However, after the copy was completed, "Old Sheet" was gone.
[image]

My code is as follows.

```
import pandas
from openpyxl import load_workbook

file_source =r'C:\Users\user\Desktop\Data.xlsx'

cols = ['iso2','cnum','country']

copy_columns=pd.read_excel(file_source, sheet_name="Old Sheet", usecols=cols).to_excel(file_source, sheet_name="New Sheet", index=False)
```

I want to keep both of "Old Sheet" and "New Sheet" existing. Please help me correcting the code.

Comment: Refer to [`this answer`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61933021/how-to-overwrite-data-on-an-existing-excel-sheet-while-preserving-all-other-shee/61933121#61933121). You need to initialize `writer.sheets` in order to let `ExcelWriter` know about the sheets.

Comment: Could you please explain it more specifically? I had changed my code according to your answer but it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(zip(['a','b','c'],[1,2,3],[6,7,5]), columns=['name','val_1','val_2'])

df.to_excel('data.xlsx',sheet_name='old_sheet',index=False)

new_df = pd.read_excel('data.xlsx',sheet_name='old_sheet', usecols=['name','val_2'])
new_df['val_2'] += 10

with pd.ExcelWriter('data.xlsx', engine='openpyxl', mode='a') as writer:
    new_df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='new_sheet',index=False)


old = pd.read_excel('data.xlsx',sheet_name='old_sheet')
new = pd.read_excel('data.xlsx',sheet_name='new_sheet')

print(old)
>>
  name  val_1  val_2
0    a      1      6
1    b      2      7
2    c      3      5


print(new)
>>
  name  val_2
0    a     16
1    b     17
2    c     15
```